# Is it possible to enable device toolbar and set resolution using javascript in chrome developer console?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm writing a chrome extension to test different page layouts of web-site. As a part of that I want to be able to enable device mode view in chrome developer tools and set desired device resolution.

Is it possible to do this using javascript in extension or any other way?

In particular, I want to do something like this:

```
chrome.devtools.enableDeviceMode();
chrome.devtools.setDeviceModeResolution(768, 1024);
```

Comment: You can do what devtools does internally - [Page.setDeviceMetricsOverride](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-setDeviceMetricsOverride) - more info in the [monitor](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/#remote).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to enable device toolbar to a chrome extension/apps. You can inspect your chrome extension by clicking the icon then choose `Inspect Popup`.

This will be the UI display. You can see that there's no device toolbar present compared to the Chrome page devTools below.

**Chrome Extension/Apps:**
[image]

**Chrome Page:**
[image]

You can only inspect and edit the elements (which can include other resources: JavaScript, CSS, images, and so on) from your extension/apps.

To change the size of the extension/apps window, you can use the sample code below:

```
var size = [window.width,window.height];

$(window).resize(function(){
    window.resizeTo(size[0],size[1]);
})
```

You can visit the documentation of [Creating a Devtools Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools#creating) and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474300/fixed-window-size-in-a-chrome-extension) for more infos.

Comment: I want to setup device mode to original page, not popup. I'm wondering if there's a way to do that, either from extenstion or directly using javascript in original window.

Comment: I see, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue next time.