# How can you prevent the virtual keyboard from resizing the browser and elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm currently building a mobile-focused React.js application that relies quite heavily on form inputs. A major recurring headache for me has been that on a text input that brings up the virtual keyboard (both on Android and iOS) resizes, or more specifically "squishes" the screen and the elements within it as well, which ends up adversely affecting my intended design aesthetic and also negatively impacts the accessibility/viewability of the app itself by making elements usually smaller and harder to both see and interact with:

Example Before Picture
[image: Example Before Picture]

Example After Virtual Keyboard Pops Up
[image: Example After Virtual Keyboard Pops Up]

Notice how the inner placeholder text also shrinks on top of the input element being moved down. This is also true for the text I would type in. The heading has been moved up out of view almost entirely and I would have to physically scroll up to see it again.

I have tried to implement a solution similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610899/disable-browser-window-resize), but unfortuantely this is not preventing the window from lengthening as it does in the second picture from my app. Here is the relevant code snippet from my `Html.js` file:

```
class Html extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    assets: PropTypes.object,
    component: PropTypes.object,
    store: PropTypes.object
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      windowHeight: 0,
      windowWidth: 0
    }
  }

  handleResize(e) {
    window.resizeTo(this.state.windowWidth, this.state.windowHeight);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      windowHeight: window.innerHeight,
      windowWidth: window.innerWidth
    }, window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize.bind(this)));
  }
```

I also don't believe that I should set any CSS property like `min-height` on the main container, because I'd like this app to be as device-agnostic as possible, but I went ahead and did that for the input elements themselves.

Here is the HTML/JSX code for the element shown above:

```
      <div className={styles.strains}>
        <h1>{this.props.options[0]}</h1>
        <div className="tagsDiv">
          <TagsInput
            ref="tags"
            placeholder={this.props.options[1]}
            className={styles2}
            maxTagLength="30"
            beforeTagAdd={this.handleBeforeTagAdd.bind(this)}
          />
          <button onClick={this.onChange.bind(this)} disabled={this.state.unknown}>Add</button>
        </div>
        <Checkbox options={this.state.cbOptions} onChange={this.handleUnknown.bind(this)} />
      </div>
```

The CSS behind it:

```
input:not([type=range]):not([type=checkbox]) {
  border: .25vh solid $activeElement !important;
  border-radius: 1vh;
  font-size: 3.5vh;
  padding-left: 3%;
  min-height: 60px !important;
  font-weight: 300;
  outline: none;
}

.tagsDiv {
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 45vh;
  }

.react-tagsinput {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25vh;
  left: 10vw;
  height: 37.25vh;
  max-width: 80vw;
}

.react-tagsinput-input {
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: 1vw;
  left: 2vw;
  bottom: 7.5vh;
  min-width: 55vw;
  max-width: 55vw;
  min-height: 60px !important;
}
```

Many thanks in advance to anyone who tries their hand at this!

Answer (score 0):

To manage how the keyboard shows up, you can use the [`VirtualKeyboard API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VirtualKeyboard_API) (No iOS support as of 03/2023).

To make the keyboard overlay the content use following code:

```js
navigator.virtualKeyboard.overlaysContent = true;
```

Then you can use something like this:

```css
display: grid;
margin: 0;
height: 100vh;
grid-template:
  "header" 1fr
  "input" auto
  "keyboard" env(keyboard-inset-height, 0px);
```