# is it possible to stop resizing a browser window with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want to stop my broswer from resizing when it's got a width by 300px.

is this possible? and how?

this is what i tried:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 300){
        //$('body').css('background-color', 'cyan');
        $(window).off('resize');
    }   
});
```

but it's not working.

Comment: kindly post your code, and what do you mean by stop resizing? containers? images? etc?

Comment: i want to stop resizing the browser..

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610899/disable-browser-window-resize?

Comment: you can do it using css media query, add this to your css: `@media(max-width: 300px){body {width: 300px;}}`

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 300) {
       window.resizeTo(300 ,$(window).height());
    }
});
```

Try this.  If your window is resized to less than 300 force the window to resize to 300 x whatever the current height is.