# How to fix browser window to specific size and disable resize?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to fix browser window to specific size and disable resize?

I want to fix the browser window to say, 750x750 pixels, without the opportunity for the user to adjust the browser window?

How can I do this in CSS (or JavaScript)? Every answer I find just fixes the size of, e.g., a `div` element, but this is not what I want.

Comment: Let users control their browser, it's not a task for an arbitrary web site.

Comment: You can’t. While ways to do this exist in theory, most browsers now either ignore any such attempts to begin with, or at least let the user decide that they want this to be ignored.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp - here is how to change the width and height. This is not something that I would recommend doing to a browser as its one of the most frustrating things that can happen from a users point of view. also almost half the web is mobile these days and that screen size is not mobile friendly

Comment: trik here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828687/is-it-possible-to-stop-resizing-a-browser-window-with-jquery

Answer (score 2):

`window.resizeTo(750,750)`

It is worth noting that this is disabled for the parent window in many browsers including Chrome and Opera for the sole reason that it's extremely poor UX.

In popup windows, such as those created by `window.open`, resizeTo works fine. For the main window, however, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

there is no possibility to give the browser window a fixed size with css or javascript. The browser settings can only be determined by the user himself.