# javascript - Disable Browser Window Resize, when Browser window resized to certain width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a script where i want to restrict the resize of browser window when we resize the browser to width 320px. The screen should not shrink below 320px.

Here is my code!!

```
        var waitForFinalEvent = (function() {
          var timers = {};
          return function(callback, ms, uniqueId) {
            if (!uniqueId) {
              uniqueId = "Don't call this twice without a uniqueId" ;
            }
            if (timers[uniqueId]) {
              clearTimeout(timers[uniqueId]);
            }
            timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
          };
        })();

        // Usage
        $(window).resize(function() {
          var output = $('.output');
          $(output).text('RESIZING...');
          // Wait for it...
          waitForFinalEvent(function() {
            $(output).text('EVENT FIRED!');
            //...
          }, 500, "some unique string");
        });
```

Comment: Check this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610899/disable-browser-window-resize

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 320) {
       window.resizeTo(300 ,$(window).height());
    }
});
```

If your window is resized to less than 320 force the window to resize to 320 x whatever the current height is.