# Is there a way to fix the Browser width/document width even while minimizing the browser window size? 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]How to fix the browser/document width to 350px so that even if the user tries to minimize the window.

The window shouldn't be minimized.

It should be fixed to 400px

Check the image above.
I need my window to be fixed for 400px even when the user forces to minimize it.

Answer (score 0):

You just set with in css and and add meta tag in header:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 350px !important; background-color: blue; color: white;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis porro iste nemo labore natus quibusdam beatae tenetur, eum numquam. Numquam expedita pariatur fuga, quia explicabo fugiat aut. Nemo, in, odio?
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when we try to resize the window it has to be fixed to 400px width....i have attached the screenshot

Comment: this didnt work in my case ...the div content has set to the width but when i resize the browser window it resized to 354px;

Comment: I don't know why you need that, but you can handle event window resize. Please reference from these questions:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610899/disable-browser-window-resize/10610931
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44427618/javascript-disable-browser-window-resize-when-browser-window-resized-to-certa

Answer (score 0):

It's easy you can refer to the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 400px !important; background-color: blue; color: white;">
Content......
</div>
</body>
</html>
```