# How can you disable resize for a popup?

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if it is possible to enable no-resize for a popup window (in Chrome).

I am aware that there have been several changes as far as the rules for this type of thing goes, which is most-likely why most of the posts I found didn't work.

I am not sure how I could achieve this, but I'm assuming it is possible.

If I run `window.onresize = () => window.resizeTo(500, 500);` in a popup, it works, but since the user resizes it then it pops back it doesn't look so great. Is there a way to just disable resizing as a whole?

Thanks!

Comment: No. That would get horribly abused and user would lose control of their workspace. Need to make the content responsive if it's important

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610899/disable-browser-window-resize

Comment: It is not intended to be done, so you will likely not find a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use fixed `width` and `height` for the pop-up and `overflow:hidden` on his parent?

**Not sure though!**

### update

**Forget what i have said!**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const popup = window;
  console.log(popup);
  popup.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    popup.resizeTo(500, 500);
  })
});
```