# i want to prevent my browser can't able to resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, resize

My application is not a responsive web application, so if resize the browser size that design is misaligned. I want to prevent user can't able to resize or minimize the browser window when they are in my application option.

I can avoid when they opened any popup on my application but that is working in browser window.

How can i solve it or is it possible ?

Comment: You can set a min-height and min-width on your web page's body. That way your page will scroll in-case a user resizes their window.

Comment: you can't stop a user doing whatever they want with their browser - just becuase you can't write a *responsive* website shouldn't mean the you get misalignment though, sounds like your design is neither here nor there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Browser Window Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610899/disable-browser-window-resize)

Answer (score 3):

It is **not possible**.

Browser is can be controlled by end user and you can't stop end user to resize it browser windows.

**Note:** This case is similar to *prevent user from closing browser window* which is also not possible.